# NullInjectorError: No provider for ReCaptchaV3Service

Tags: angular, dependency-injection

I need to integrate reCaptchaV3 so I followed the [ng-recaptcha-npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-recaptcha) 
Here is the base code that I implemented with the help of the `ng-recaptcha-npm`.
**MyModule**
`import { RecaptchaV3Module, RECAPTCHA_V3_SITE_KEY } from 'ng-recaptcha';`

```
imports: [
  ...
  RecaptchaV3Module
],
providers: [
  AuthResolver,
  { provide: RECAPTCHA_V3_SITE_KEY, useValue: environment.RECAPTCHA_KEY }
]
```

**MyComponent**
`import { ReCaptchaV3Service } from 'ng-recaptcha';`

```
constructor(
  ...
  private recaptchaV3Service: ReCaptchaV3Service
) {}


public onSendClicked(): void {
  this.recaptchaV3Service.execute('importantAction')
  .subscribe((token) => {
    console.log('token = ', token);
});
```

But it returns a bad response and here is the console error.

```
NullInjectorError: No provider for ReCaptchaV3Service!
NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(AppModule)[ReCaptchaV3Service -> ReCaptchaV3Service -> ReCaptchaV3Service]:
NullInjectorError: No provider for ReCaptchaV3Service!
at NullInjector.get (core.js:1085)
at R3Injector.get (core.js:16968)
at R3Injector.get (core.js:16968)
at R3Injector.get (core.js:16968)
at NgModuleRef$1.get (core.js:36342)
at Object.get (core.js:33985)
at getOrCreateInjectable (core.js:5848)
at Module.ɵɵdirectiveInject (core.js:21116)
at NodeInjectorFactory.ContactUsComponent_Factory [as factory] (contact-us.component.ts:19)
at getNodeInjectable (core.js:5993)
at resolvePromise (zone-evergreen.js:798)
at resolvePromise (zone-evergreen.js:750)
at zone-evergreen.js:860
at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:399)
at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:41645)
at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:398)
at Zone.runTask (zone-evergreen.js:167)
at drainMicroTaskQueue (zone-evergreen.js:569)
```

Comment: Can you create a Minimal Reproducible Example in [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com) ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

add ReCaptchaV3Service in provider

```
import { ReCaptchaV3Service } from 'ng-recaptcha';
    imports: [
      ...
      RecaptchaV3Module
    ],
    providers: [
    ReCaptchaV3Service,
      AuthResolver,
      { provide: RECAPTCHA_V3_SITE_KEY, useValue: environment.RECAPTCHA_KEY }
    ]
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. By the way, it returns same issues. :(

Comment: can you share console log after you added above mentioned code ?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem.
I moved the base code `import { RecaptchaV3Module, RECAPTCHA_V3_SITE_KEY } from 'ng-recaptcha';` and `{ provide: RECAPTCHA_V3_SITE_KEY, useValue: environment.RECAPTCHA_KEY }` to the root module (app.module.ts) and it worked.